# Spring Boot not inserting data from data.sql file?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I have to classes, like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "user_name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "pass_word", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "roles", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String roles;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Contact> contacts = new HashSet<Contact>();
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contact")
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "contact_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "firstName", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "displayName", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String displayName;

    @Column(name = "email", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "photoPath", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String photoPath;

    @Column(name = "note", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String note;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
}
```

In `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/email_project
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password= root

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL= debug

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

In `data.sql`

```
 INSERT INTO `email_project`.`user` ( first_name, last_name, user_name, pass_word, roles) VALUES ( 'a','a','a','a', 'ROLE_USER');

INSERT INTO `email_project`.`user` (first_name, last_name, user_name, pass_word, roles)VALUES ( 'b','b','b','b', 'ROLE_USER');

INSERT INTO `email_project`.`contact` (firstName, lastName, displayName, email, photoPath, note, user_id) VALUES ('a', 'a','a','a','a','a', 1)
```

When I tried inserting only users, that worked fine. But when I tried inserting contact, it fails. How can I fix this?

Here is some, reasonable, part of error message:

org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #3 of URL [file:/F:/Workspaces_IntelliJ_Spring_Projects/MyProject/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO `email_project`.`contact` (firstName, lastName, displayName, email, photoPath, note, user_id) VALUES ('a', 'a','a','a','a','a', 1); nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'firstName' in 'field list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think sql might set your column names as "first_name" instead of "firstName" and so on. This might happen if something regarding the hibernate naming strategy is not working okay and the @Column is basically not setting the given name in the columns.

Firstly check your database and see how the columns are named in the contract table. If it is as I said above changing the column names from "firstName" to "first_name" inside the insert should work just fine.

If that solves the issue you could also try adding those this property value to solve the hibernate naming strategy:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```